# In C++ why is it here that when trying to add two digits from a string doesn't work even though the the digits are correct but sum is not.?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer, char

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="145245";
    cout<<s[0]+s[3];
    return 0;
}
```

hello i am beginner
I tried to find the solution in geeksforgeeks, stackoverflow, tutorialpoint but couldn't find answer to this.

expected output:3
output:99

Comment: A string has characters of type `char`. When you add 2 of them they are promoted to `int`.

Comment: the character "1" is code 49. "2" is code 50.  49 + 50 = 99.    That's true for both ASCII and unicode - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: You have to understand that in C++ (and in C) the character `'5'` is not equal to `5`. If anything, the character `'5'`, when converted to integer, takes the value `53`. https://www.asciitable.com/ . That is why you get the numbers that you get. To convert to the integral interpretation of the character, look for `std::atoi` and similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can convert a character to int for example '1' - '0' will give integer value 1
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="145245";
    cout<<s[0]-'0' + s[3] -'0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pure Magic? Care to explain *why* adding the secret codes `-'0'` happens to work?

Comment: The code above calculates the sum of two digits in the string 's' by converting them from characters to integers using the ASCII representation. SO to calculate each digit numerically we subtract '0', which is subtracting the ASCII value. I hope it explains.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more precise explanation for the answer above me.
`s[0]` is a char. A char is also an int, however, it will be converted to ascii code. so adding two chars directly will return the addition of their perspective ascii codes. the answer above suggests running

```
s[0] - '0'
```

Which forces the compiler to treat s[0] as a number and return it's value ( as an int ).

If you are planning to start a career with C++, I suggest you read the [documentation](https://devdocs.io/cpp/) as it helps with simple yet very helpful concepts and explains how code works and causes of undefined behavior.

Comment: Started an edit to fix a small error in the content. Then found another and another and another, so I gave up on the edit. The overall idea is correct, but some of the details are wrong. `s[0] - '0'` results in an `int`, but  ` char` is not an `int`. They are not converted to ascii code, they simply are encoded, and not necessarily in ascii.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys I missed the point that s[i] was a char and was working on it thinking that maybe it converted itself to integer otherwise i would have checked how to convert char to int. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @user4581301 char is presented in memory in the same format as an int. and as you said, the value is depended on how character encoding, ascii is just the most common and the easier example. Thanks for the clarification.